# I have 4 linear transforms T1 to T4.

Tags: linear-transformations

I have 4 linear transforms T1 to T4.
I am going to find final transformation T4oT3oT2oT1 to vector e1=(1,0).
should I apply T1 yhen T2 then....or I should apply T4 then T3 then...(THANKS)

Answer (score 1):

Apply $T_1$ first, then $T_2$, etc.; that's how composition is defined.

Comment: Thank you very much